# Terraform - why this is not causing circular dependency?

Tags: terraform

Terraform registry AWS VPC example [terraform-aws-vpc/examples/complete-vpc/main.tf](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/blob/v2.21.0/examples/complete-vpc/main.tf) has the code below which seems to me a circular dependency.

```
data "aws_security_group" "default" {
  name   = "default"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
}

module "vpc" {
  source = "../../"

  name = "complete-example"

...
 # VPC endpoint for SSM
  enable_ssm_endpoint              = true
  ssm_endpoint_private_dns_enabled = true
  ssm_endpoint_security_group_ids  = [data.aws_security_group.default.id] # <----- 

...
```

**data.aws_security_group.default** refers to "module.vpc.vpc_id" and **module.vpc** refers to "data.aws_security_group.default.id".

Please explain why this does not cause an error and how come module.vpc can refer to data.aws_security_group.default.id?

Comment: Because the dependency graph works on individual elements, not modules. Wherever you are passing the security group ID to as part of `ssm_endpoint_security_group_ids` doesn't have a circular dependency on the security group. But it is completely unnecessary because you could just pass the resource's security group directly inside the module. To be sure you'd have to post the source of the module as well.

Comment: Hi @ydaetskcoR, thanks but still not sure why. In my understanding, data source runs first to retrieve data, and would require an existing resource, in this case the default security group of module.vpc which has not been created yet. I wonder why it does not fail.

Comment: It doesn't run before the VPC is created because of the interpolation. I'd still expect it to fail on first creation though because the security group creation will happen at the same time as the VPC creation (assuming it also interpolates the VPC ID and that the module output comes directly from the VPC resource) so at that point the security group isn't created. But more importantly it's impossible to really tell concretely how things work if you don't post the source of your module. But considering your module looks very complex I'd attempt to produce a [mcve] of this instead.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Code is all in Github of the Terraform Registry AWS VPC https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc and the example is https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/tree/master/examples/complete-vpc in the github.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Terraform language, a module creates a separate namespace but it is *not* a node in the dependency graph. Instead, each of the module's Input Variables and Output Values are separate nodes in the dependency graph.

For that reason, this configuration contains the following dependencies:

- The `data.aws_security_group.default` resource depends on `module.vpc.vpc_id`, which is specifically the `output "vpc_id"` block in that module, not the module as a whole.
- The `vpc` module's `variable "ssm_endpoint_security_group_ids"` variable depends on the `data.aws_security_group.default` resource.

We can't see the inside of the `vpc` module in your question here, but the above is okay as long as there is no dependency connection between `output "vpc_id"` and `variable "ssm_endpoint_security_group_ids"` inside the module.

I'm assuming that such a connection does not exist, and so the evaluation order of objects here would be something like this:

- `aws_vpc.example` in `module.vpc` is created (I just made up a name for this because it's not included in your question)
- The `output "vpc_id"` in `module.vpc` is evaluated, referring to `module.vpc.aws_vpc.example`, and producing `module.vpc.vpc_id`.
- `data.aws_security_group.default` in the root module is read, using the value of `module.vpc.vpc_id`.
- The `variable "ssm_endpoint_security_group_ids"` for `module.vpc` is evaluated, referring to `data.aws_security_group.default`.
- `aws_vpc_endpoint.example` in `module.vpc` is created, including a reference to `var.ssm_endpoint_security_group_ids`.

Notice that in all of the above I'm talking about objects *in* modules, not modules themselves. The modules serve only to create separate namespaces for objects, and then the separate objects themselves (which includes individual `variable` and `output` blocks) are what participate in the dependency graph.

---

Normally this design detail isn't visible: Terraform normally just uses it to potentially optimize concurrency by beginning work on part of a module before the whole module is ready to process. In some interesting cases like this though, you can also intentionally exploit this design so that an operation for the calling module can be explicitly sandwiched between two operations for the child module.

Another reason why we might make use of this capability is when two modules naturally depend on one another, such as in [an experimental module I built](https://github.com/terraformnet/terraform-aws-vpc-region) that hides some of the tricky details of setting up VPC peering connections:

```
locals {
  vpc_nets = {
    us-west-2 = module.vpc_usw2
    us-east-1 = module.vpc_use1
  }
}

module "peering_usw2" {
  source = "../../modules/peering-mesh"

  region_vpc_networks = local.vpc_nets
  other_region_connections = {
    us-east-1 = module.peering_use1.outgoing_connection_ids
  }

  providers = {
    aws = aws.usw2
  }
}

module "peering_use1" {
  source = "../../modules/peering-mesh"

  region_vpc_networks = local.vpc_nets
  other_region_connections = {
    us-west-2 = module.peering_usw2.outgoing_connection_ids
  }

  providers = {
    aws = aws.use1
  }
}
```

(the above is just a relevant snippet from [an example in the module repository](https://github.com/terraformnet/terraform-aws-vpc-region/blob/def3bf87e2f8aa91c223273942eb3ec5a4febabf/examples/simple/main.tf).)

In the above case, the `peering-mesh` module is carefully designed to allow this mutual referencing, internally deciding for each pair of regional VPCs which one will be the peering initiator and which one will be the peering accepter. The `outgoing_connection_ids` output refers only to the `aws_vpc_peering_connection` resource and the `aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter` refers only to `var.other_region_connections`, and so the result is a bunch of concurrent operations to create `aws_vpc_peering_connection` resources, followed by a bunch of concurrent operations to create `aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter` resources.

Comment: Appreciate the reply from the person behind TF 0.12. Thanks for the work. I think I get the picture. Is it the reason [depends_on module]( https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18239) will not happen? Although we users may assume a TF module is a kind-of-atomic unit (node in DAG?), all the resources in the root module and the TF modules are laid flat in one place, and a DAG is created from all of them. Hope this understanding is correct.